# for-loop setting length variable when converting from nodelist

Tags: javascript

phew! That was a long title.

I'm reading WROX' book on Professional JavaScript for web developers and I came across this sample code, and I was just wondering if that was best practice:

```
function convertToArray(nodes) {
   array = new Array();
   for (var i=0, len=nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
      array.push(nodes[i]);
   }
   return array;
}
```

The thing that's got me scratching my head is the "len=nodes.length". Am I wrong in thinking that the first sentence in a for-loop is only run once? Is there a reason you'd want to set a variable (len) to the length of the nodeList before running through it? Would you do that to a normal array as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is for performance reasons. A local variable is faster for several reasons:

- The the length will need to be accessed all the time in the loop, once per every iteration;
- A local variable lookup is faster than member lookup;
- If `nodes` is an array, then `.length` is a magic property that may take a bit longer to retrieve than a member variable.
- If `nodes` is an ActiveX object, then `.length` might result in a method call into the object, so that's the most expensive operation of all.

Answer (score 3):

While we're discussing micro-optimizations, the following should be even faster:

```
function convertToArray(nodes) {
    var i = nodes.length,
        array = new Array(i); // potentially faster than `array = []`
                              //  --  see comments

    while(i--)
        array[i] = nodes[i];

    return array;
}
```

It needs one less local variable, uses a `while` and not a `for` loop and uses array assignment instead of the function call `push()`.

Also, because <del>we're counting down</del> we pre-allocate the array's slots, the array's length doesn't have to be changed each iteration step, <del>but only on the first one</del>.

Comment: This can be optimized even further by replacing "array=[]" with "array=new Array(nodes.length)". This way the array won't need to grow all the time (that causes memory reallocations).

Comment: @Vilx: I think you're right; but keep in mind that parsing the array literal is faster than calling the constructor, and as long as `node.length` is not 'too big', the first assignment will still create a dense array (most JS engines differentiate between dense and sparse arrays), so there might be a performance hit instead...